# Can I configure Apache to redirect at a specified timeout?

Tags: apache, apache-config

I How to configure Apache so I can redirect to another page on a specified TimeOut. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any possible solution how to do this in Apache.

Still, if you are using PHP, try playing with PHP `register_shutdown_function` function.

Sample code:

```
set_time_limit(1);
function shutdown () {
    if ( ! defined('FINISHED')) {
        header('Location: /timeout');
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

while (true) {}

define('FINISHED', 1);
```

Still this will be executed on fatal errors as well and after manual `die()` or `exit()` calls inside your scripts.